# How to insert a newline character to an array of characters

Tags: ruby, character, newline

I want to insert a newline character into an array of characters which initially is a string. Let's say I have a variable `myvar = "Blizzard"`. A string is formed from an array of characters. How can I insert a newline character inside it? In hope of making an output like this:

```
"B
 lizzard"
```

I tried this:

```
myvar[1] = "\n"
```

but it's not working, and the output is like this:

```
"B\nlizzard"
```

My goal is to make the output like this:

```
B
l
i
z
z
a
r
d
```

without using `puts`. I have to do it by inserting newline characters into the array. Can someone point out where my mistake is, and if possible help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add `\n` you can use this:

```
myvar = "Blizzard"
myvar.chars.map { |c| c + "\n" }.join.strip
```

Or better @Uri solution:

```
myvar.chars.join "\n"
```

But you can puts letters one on the line with next code:

```
myvar.chars.each { |c| puts c }
```

or:

```
myvar.each_char { |c| puts c } # for ruby >= 2.0
```

by Darek Nędza

Comment: Well, starting from Ruby ~2.0 You may use `each_char` instead of `chars.each`. I think it may be faster.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, yes it's a bit faster.

Comment: Well thanks Nedza for that works with output, uh but err.. Actually that's not my goal, I mean not the output like that, I mean the string must be added newline character for every one character, and my friend told me about using for 1 in 0..(text.length -1 ) and if statement, but I really don't know what he means. But thanks anyway this is a new info for me too :)

Comment: Well, this `'Blizzard'.chars.join("\n")` did exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
'Blizzard'.chars.join("\n")
# => "B\nl\ni\nz\nz\na\nr\nd"
```

If all you want is to print the characters each in a new row you can do the following:

```
puts 'Blizzard'.chars
```

Output:

```
B
l
i
z
z
a
r
d
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done `myvar[1] = "\n"` correctly. Your problem is not how you did it, but what you are expecting.

You seem to be confusing the inspection of a string and the `puts` output of the string. Inspection is what is displayed as the return value as in irb, and it is a meta-representation of what you have. And as long as it is a string, it will be delimited by double quotes, and all the special characters will be escaped with a backslash `\`. If you have a new line character, that would be represented as `"\n"`. On the other hand, when you pass the string to `puts`, you will get the output according to what the special characters represent.

What you displayed as what you want (the one in multiple lines) should be the result of `puts`. You will never get such thing as inspection of the string.

Comment: Thanks sawa for pointing out that to me, it gives me more clarity abuot this issue :)